# Text from file not equal text in tag id

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text.txt file which contain tag name:

> tagforinserttext

And I have a page with next code

```
<div class="header">
    <h1 id="tagforinserttext"></h1>
</div>
```

In JS code I read file and get "tagforinserttext" into variable "tag".
Then I try to insert some text, using

```
document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "sometext";
```

But text now inserted...

I found that getElementById(tag) don`t have a link to tag in page, but if I write getElementById('tagforinserttext') then its work!

Then I tried to compare the variable with the text and got that they are not equal ... they are equal, because the text that is in the variable when output via alert () is equal to 'tagforinserttext'

I can`t understand where I make a mistake and I hope for your help.

Comment: my guess is the text is not what you think it is. `console.log(escape(tag))`

Comment: First you need to create a variable called tag like var tag ="codes for your js file reading" and then you need to paste that contents to h1 by  document.getElementById(tagforinserttext).innerHTML = tag ;.Hope this helps.

Comment: @epascarello thx! log show "tagforinserttext%0D". I tried to replace it, but nothing has changed, what can I do about it? I do not know other options to get rid of the letter.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal This work correct, but if I write  document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "text"; then it dont work, becuse tag  = "tagforinserttext%0D" not "tagforinserttext". And now I cant understad how delete "%0D", because replace function not change anything

Comment: @ZeT try using `.replace('%0D', '')`

Comment: So you have a line break in your file. This is why JSON is a lot better than a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I informed you to do

```
console.log(escape(tag))
```

which shows you have %0D which is a line break so you have a line break in the file you are reading. So you can remove the line break from the file or use a regular expression to remove the line break.

```
tag = tag.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,"")
```

A better solution, use JSON so you can parse and get the string out easier.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I need!